# What documents are needed for a UK Visitor Visa?

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork

I am Planning to Travel to UK in July beginning and planning to have Stay there for a Month.

Brief details in My Case :

I am Currently working with a Listed Bank in India and Having vintage of 2 years, My real sister and Brother in law is Residing at UK, at the time of my visit i will stay with them and they will arrange my Food and Accommodation.

Request you to Guide Process to follow and Documents required to Avoid VISA Rejection.

My Specific Questions are on following Points :
- What Documents i Need to Get from My Employer
- What Amount of Balance Do i need to Maintain at the time of Visa Process
- Which Documents will be Required from my sister's Side

Answer (score 2):

According to [Family Visitor visa - Documents you must provide](https://www.gov.uk/family-visit-visa/documents-you-must-provide) the only thing you might need to provide from your employer are pay slips.

In particular, what they're wanting is proof that you have "enough money to support yourself during your trip, eg bank statements or payslips for the last 6 months".

From your sisters side you'll need the following:

- a letter of invitation from them
- evidence of their financial and employment circumstances, eg bank statements or payslips
- evidence of their immigration circumstances in the UK showing they're permanently settled or have asylum humanitarian status in the UK, eg a valid visa or immigration stamp in their passport

Seems to me that it might be easier to apply for a [General Visitor visa](https://www.gov.uk/general-visit-visa/documents-you-must-provide), however, and say you're visiting a friend instead of a family member idk.

Comment: But what i Need to Know is Account Balance that i am suppose to Maintain in My Account. In addition to it any other Things to be kept in Mind other than that what is available on UK Govt Website.

Comment: Link is broken.